# How to use JsInterop in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am playing with Gwt and want to try JsInterop.

I defined a simple POJO annotated with @JsType.
Idea sees annotation type in the project, but building fails with error that annotation class is undefined.

GWT version 2.8.1.
GWT maven plugin is gwt-maven-plugin 1.0-rc-8.

Compiler options are:

```
  <compilerArgs>
     <compileArg>-XjsInteropMode</compileArg>
     <compileArg>-generateJsInteropExports</compileArg>
     <compileArg>JS</compileArg>
  </compilerArgs> 


[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/egnyte/demo/gwt/StockWatcherSample-master/src/main/java/de/google/gwt/stockwatcher/client/sub/Mesage.java:[5,37] package com.google.gwt.core.client.js does not exist
[ERROR] /home/egnyte/demo/gwt/StockWatcherSample-master/src/main/java/de/google/gwt/stockwatcher/client/sub/Mesage.java:[7,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class JsType
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.119 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-06T16:09:52+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/258M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project stockwatcher: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/egnyte/demo/gwt/StockWatcherSample-master/src/main/java/de/google/gwt/stockwatcher/client/sub/Mesage.java:[5,37] package com.google.gwt.core.client.js does not exist
[ERROR] /home/egnyte/demo/gwt/StockWatcherSample-master/src/main/java/de/google/gwt/stockwatcher/client/sub/Mesage.java:[7,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class JsType
```

Comment: Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)

Comment: @MarcoSalerno, you have no experience with gwt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@JsType` import is wrong. It should be

```
import jsinterop.annotations.JsType;
```

If that doesn't work, make sure you actually have `jsinterop-annotations` version 1.0.1 in your dependencies.

If you are seeing the old annotation, then you are using GWT 2.7 or earlier in addition to GWT 2.8 - never a good idea to mix versions.

Comment: Thx, I forget to refresh imports in idea after upgrading GWT up to 2.8. So maven worked with 2.8, while IDE mislead me with with imports from 2.7. Link to dependency jsinterop-annotations also helped, cause I haven't met it anywhere in documents.

Comment: jsinterop-base is another good dependency to have - if you are using Elemental2 at all, you'll pick it up transitively. It includes a lot of "glue" that we would have otherwise used JSNI for in the past, and will still work in GWT3 when it arrives.